Button is not available until reCaptcha check | Selenium, Python
I can't pass through a login form where the Login button is disabled and has a ::before pseudo and it seems that it's triggered when the reCaptcha checkmark appears (or they get the proper response from recaptcha)
I can pass the reCaptcha with the help of a 3rd party solver API but it doesn't trigger the ::before and if my automation clicks the reCaptcha checkbox it resets the captcha and I should solve by hand.
disabled button
<span class="button-module__kindPrimary--kixJj button-preview-module__disabled--ip4tO login-primary-button-module__button--O9TI4 login-primary-button-module__buttonLight--YnR0d" type="submit" disabled="" style="--login-button-background-color: #007DAD;">
   ::before
   <span class="button-module__label--9WIcY login-primary-button-module__buttonLabel--a1mbj">Log in</span>
</span>

enabled button
<button class="button-module__kindPrimary--kixJj login-primary-button-module__button--O9TI4 login-primary-button-module__buttonLight--YnR0d" type="submit" form="loginForm" style="--login-button-background-color: #007DAD;">
   ::before
   <span class="button-module__label--9WIcY login-primary-button-module__buttonLabel--a1mbj">Log in</span>
</button>```


Anyone can help how can I solve this issue and make this event triggered or the button clickable so I can sign in after captcha is solved? 

FYI if relevant: basically the captcha is solved by getting the resolution id and then it is sent back as the value of the captcha element)


response2_id = "*1234*"
recaptcha_response_element = browser.find_element(By.ID, "g-recaptcha-response")
browser.execute_script(f'arguments[0].value = "{response2_id}";', recaptcha_response_element)

